# branch and bound

Tags: algorithm, search, branch-and-bound

Can someone explain the branch and bound search technique for me? I need to find a path with the smallest cost from any start node to an end node of any random graph using branch and bound search algorithm.

Comment: What's the context?  That would make it easier to give a better explanation.

Answer (score 7):

The basic idea of B & B is:

1. When solving an optimisation problem ("Find an X satisfying criteria Y so as to minimise the cost f(X)"), you build a solution piece by piece -- at any point in time, you have a *partial solution*, which has a *cost*.
2. If the nature of the problem is such that the cost of a partial solution can only stay the same or go up as you continue adding pieces to it, then you know that **there's no point continuing to add pieces to a partial solution if there's already a full solution with lower cost**.  In this case, you can abandon (or "prune", or "fathom") further processing of this partial solution.

Many problems have the latter property, making B & B a widely applicable algorithm technique.

The process of searching for solutions can be represented by a *search tree*, where the root node represents the starting point where no decisions have been made, and each edge leading from a node represents a decision about something to be included in a partial solution.  Each node is a partial solution comprising the decisions made (edges) from the root to that node.

**Example:** if we want to solve a Sudoku puzzle, the root node would represent the board with just the originally supplied numbers filled in; there might be 9 edges from this root, each representing the decision to assign a number 1-9 to the top-left cell.  Each of those 9 partial solution nodes could have 8 branches, representing the valid assignments to the cell at position (1, 2), and so on.  Usually, each edge represents a recursion step in a program.

With B & B, in the best case a good solution is found early, meaning that unpromising areas of the search tree can be pruned near the root; but in the worst case, the entire tree of valid solutions will be generated.  For this reason B & B is usually only used to solve problems for which no faster algorithm is known (such as NP-hard problems).

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://horicky.blogspot.com/2008/07/branch-and-bound-algorithm.html) provides a graphical representation of concepts related to B & B.

[This link](http://www.codersource.net/csharp_branch_and_bound_algorithm_implementation.aspx) provides an explanation of the algorithm and **sample C# code** in a downloadable zip file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of references about branch and bound algorithms in the web.

[here](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cis680/cis680Ch20.html) you can find some theoretical explanation.

whereas the code in C# is [here](http://www.codersource.net/Samples/Branch_Bound_code.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Fantastic answer @j_random_hacker !!!!

See pg 439 (example 18.2) in Papadimitriou and Steiglitz, Combinatorial Optimization.

This book is a classic, and it discusses your exact problem.